# Query on all layer features with boundlessgeo sdk

Tags: openlayers, query, boundless-suite, react

I'm currently implementing a webgis by using the reactjs components from the boundlessgeo sdk.

I'm using the QueryBuilder component in order to query for features but It always performs the query on the currently loaded features for a given layer. 
So, if there is a feature that meets the search criteria but is not loaded on the client side, the query will return no results.

How can I do to perform a query on all the layer's features although not all features were still loaded in the client side?

Does anyone faced this issue?

The same applies for the feature table component, It always contains just the features currently loaded.